# highchart export button not show

Tags: highcharts

I´m prooving highcharts with a simple graph in angular . But export button not show . I add the script in html page :

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>  
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>  
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

and add the properties in chart :

```
export :true,
navigation: {
  buttonOptions: {
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 0
  }
},
```

but nothing.

this is te app url :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkncp8

Comment: If you think my answer is correct please accept it, just click the icon below the up/down arrow.

Comment: thanks , i prooved and works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo on your call (`exporting` not `export`), also you should set menu items:

```js
exporting: {
      buttons: {
        contextButton: {
          menuItems: [
            'viewFullscreen', 'separator', 'downloadPNG',
            'downloadSVG', 'downloadPDF', 'separator', 'downloadXLS'
          ]
        },
      },
      enabled: true,
    },
navigation: {
  buttonOptions: {
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 0
  }
},
```

And you need to import `exporting modules` to this same file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/export-data')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/annotations')(Highcharts);

declare var require: any;
(...)
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ylkg8

API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting

Answer (score 0):

```
exporting: {
        menuItemDefinitions: {
            // Custom definition
            label: {
                onclick: function () {
                    this.renderer.label(
                        'You just clicked a custom menu item',
                        100,
                        100
                    )
                        .attr({
                            fill: '#a4edba',
                            r: 5,
                            padding: 10,
                            zIndex: 10
                        })
                        .css({
                            fontSize: '1.5em'
                        })
                        .add();
                },
                text: 'Show label'
            }
        },
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                menuItems: ['downloadPNG', 'downloadSVG', 'separator', 'label']
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion